# C++ missing symbols link error with msbuild but not visual studio (debug)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, linker

I have a native C++ solution with a library and a console application (tool) that consumes the library. The library has quite a few external symbols that are not used by the tool (the library is also consumed later in the main program which supplies these symbols)

Everything builds fine in Visual Studio (2017/2019/2022)

When building the solution with msbuild the release build is fine but the debug build fails with nearly 200 missing symbols. This is important as this is how the automation builds things.

```
msbuild MyLibrary.sln /p:Configuration=debug /p:Platform=Win32
```

example link error:

```
mylibrary.lib(scope.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl Cnxres(char const *,int &)" (?Cnxres@@YA_NPBDAAH@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall MyScope::getBooleanExpressionResult(void)" (?getBooleanExpressionResult@MyScope@@QAE_NXZ)
```

This is consuming the library as a static i.e. mylibrary.lib
These missing symbols are all unused by the tool and are external to the library.

If however, I change the tool to not link against the library but to recompile the relevant source code (3 cxx files) and thus link with the objs then msbuild succeeds.

I am struggling to explain the behaviour and really I would prefer to consume the library as that will allow me to separate the build process

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information. VS uses msbuild under the hood. Does the debug build config work through VS? If so, how does the command line differ to yours (you can see this in the project settings and in the build outputs if verbosity is high enough).

Comment: @Mansoor it is always a balance between brevity and providing enough details. I don't think airing Visual Studio's dirt laundry will help here.

Comment: You should provide a [MRE], so we don't have to speculate.

Comment: If I link the individual .obj files instead of the .lib then the debug build works